# How to validate select2 for error - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

The form I am using have a select2 dropdown which fills like

```
 $('.DropdownPINOption').select2({
     placeholder: '-- Select your PIN --',
     allowClear: true,
     tags: true,
     data: data.data.Table
 });
```

and the problem came when I migrated data from another database. Because the value I am trying to fill on this dropdown is either null or will be not a value in the field on my dropdown.

This is my code

```
 if (data.data.Table[0].Current_Permanent_Overseas_Address_PIN_Code != null)
    $("#4txtPin").val(data.data.Table[0].Current_Permanent_Overseas_Address_PIN_Code).change();
```

which is throwing an error: **Cannot read property 'length' of null**

So I did this :

```
$('#4txtPin option').each(function () {
   if (this.value == data.data.Table[0].Current_Permanent_Overseas_Address_PIN_Code) {
       $("#4txtPin").val(data.data.Table[0].Current_Permanent_Overseas_Address_PIN_Code).change();
   }
});
```

It's not showing any error and it works as expected. But it doesn't feel right. Is there a better solution available for select2 ? how can I show placeholder when an invalid value comes?